# Is there a Stack Exchange for Consumer Electronics questions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I see there is an electronics.stackexchange.com site, but the FAQ explains it isn't for asking questions about consumer electronics. Where should I ask such a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there's currently [a proposal for a Consumer Electronics site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) on Area 51:

> Proposed Q&A site for enthusiasts and users of electronic items (computers, mobile phones, batteries, etc.). Ask any question that relates to usage and features of consumer electronics.

Note that the site is still in the Definition phase, though, and needs more attention before it can be launched. As noted in the comments, if this site proposal doesn't get much attention it will probably suffer the same fate as [Electronic Gadgets](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/) (closed after 63 days in beta).  Feel free to follow, share, and propose some example questions for [Consumer Electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) to help it along!

Comment: Isn't that going to suffer the same fate as http://gadgets.stackexchange.com? I mean, the scopes sound nearly identical.

Comment: @AlEverett Yeah, that could be. Perhaps that's why there's a new proposal? ;)

Comment: @AlEverett - The problem wasn't that the scope was bad, was that it didn't generate good Q&A. That's partly due to the fact that the scope is huge and fragmented.  Perhaps v2 will have more interest from experts and avoid these problems somehow.  Might as well give it a try!

Comment: There already exists [apple.se] for iPods, iPhones and other such consumer electronics, and [android.se] for android devices, too. Networking electronics like routers are typically on-topic for [SU].

Comment: In 2018, this proposal no longer exists...

Answer (score 8):

As a moderator on Electrical Engineering (aka electronics.stackexchange.com), I want to say a big THANK YOU and +1 for reading the FAQ and refraining from posting your off-topic question.

We've discussed the non-engneering connotations of  "electronics" [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/474) and [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149/possible-name-change/151#151).

[Superuser](https://superuser.com/) does support some questions about computers.  Their FAQ reads:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Is your consumer electronics question about interfacing some electronics with your computer?  If so, you're in luck!

If not, the [Consumer Electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) proposal is the long-term home of your question.  Unfortunately, its previous incarnation, [Gadgets](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/), fizzled and died.  It's hard to have good Q&A about consumer electronics, simply because they're so numerous and transitory.  Good Q&A requires experts to answer the hard questions, and you need a lot of experts to answer questions about all the products that get asked about on a site like this.

For now, you need to go to [one of the many other Q&A sites on the web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions) or to contact your device manufacturer/vendor helpline.