# I have a question about a bug with a smart watch, where would I ask this?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have had a problem with my Amazfit Bip smartwatch, where would I ask a question about this?

Comment: For a specific OS?

Comment: I looked it up and it says "The Bip runs on its proprietary OS in conjunction with the Mi Fit companion app for iOS and Android."

Comment: I've been asking, because we keep an Android and iOS site here.

Comment: Ok, I don't think this would fit into one of those categories though.

Comment: Probably better asked on the product-specific support forum.  This is probably the best option for any question that's strictly product related.

Comment: See [Is there a Stack Exchange for Consumer Electronics questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110484/2952320) - various site proposals have been made in the past, but all failed.

Comment: What kind of problem are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Android Enthusiasts SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/), which has a [smartwatch](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smartwatch) tag.  But it might be better to ask your question on a support forum for Amazfit products.